# jQuery code assist in Aptana Studio 3.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, aptana, aptana3

This is not duplicate question because lots of things changed in Aptana Studio 3.1.1 and there is no question regardnig that version.

I would like to have code assist for jQuery in Aptana Studio.
I already installed jQuery bundle. But I still don't get any code assist for my code.

I type for example:
$("div#chat").
After typing dot I should see list of all jQuery functions. But I don't see anything.

What I have to do to fix it?

Comment: do you see it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>?

Comment: [This shows it as an OPEN bug since 3.0.7 and has not since been fixed](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Aptana-Studio-Changelog-29555.html) There has since been discussion about using a quickfix from an old Commit via [This Post](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3305). Read Kevin Lindsey's Comment.

Comment: @balexandre Nope. Empty list.

Comment: It works for me as expected. Also note that the linked ticket above shows it as _fixed_ in 3.0.7. The comment references that there is a more general case that will eventually be fixed that solves the issues for all jQuery-like libraries (not just jQuery itself)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works for me as expected using the directions here:

1. Commands > Install Bundle > jQuery
2. Right click on a project, select Properties > Project Build Path and select the checkbox for jQuery 1.6.2.

If you don't do the second part, you'll just get snippets. This prevents you from needing to copy it into every project.

Comment: If you're using the Mac version see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846411/jquery-jquery-mobile-aptana-studio-3/14846480#14846480

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.
If you want to have code hinting for jquery you need to download (uncompressed) jQuery library and place it in the same folder as your script.

This is working but it is not satisfying me. I have many folders and I don't want to duplicate jQuery file over all folders.