# Jquery/Jquery mobile - Aptana Studio 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, aptana, syntax-highlighting

I can't seem to find a good post for turning on syntax highlighting or intellisense for jquery/jquery mobile in Aptana Studio 3 for Mac.

What I have found is out of date or the instructions don't match the version I have installed ([like this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721124/how-to-enable-jquery-support-in-aptana-studio-3).

Is it possible in Studio 3 for Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well right after I posted I found this [answer on a SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262320/jquery-code-assist-in-aptana-studio-3-1-1?rq=1) (which like all others didn't have the correct instructions, but this one was close enough to where I managed to find it)

Here's what I did:
1) Right click the project folder -> Properties
2) Click Formatter
3) Check 'Enable project specific settings'
4) Click Ok